# Object is not empty but it says it's an undefined

Tags: json, react-native

I want to check if a variable is equal to an attribute inside an array of objects, which is this one:
[image: json]

At the 2nd if(), `this.state.diccionarioLogos.length` it returns false, but I checked it and it has an object inside

[image: codigo]

Also, when I try to get to an attribute inside a Text tag, it also gives this error, saying that it's undefined.

[image: error]

Here's my fetch

[image: fetch]

What am I doing wrong? I want to get the base64 image only if it matches.

Comment: Please never add code as images!  Is `this.state.diccionarioLogos` the array of objects (first image)?

Comment: share your code, please...................

Comment: @Tim yes, the first image is dicionarioLogos, and what do you mean by not adding code as images? If you're referring to the base64, I cant help that because the provides sends us that.

Comment: @Asad what more code do you need?

Comment: Replace your screenshots with code...... so that we can copy and run it, try to fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's probably happening is that `transformarImagen` is called before the array of logos is actually populated, `fetch` is an asynchronous functions, so it takes a little while to process and set the state, in the meanwhile `transformarImages` gets executed.

You should probably wait for `getLogos` to complete its execution, one option could be to return the promise from `getLogos` and execute `transformarImagen` once the array is set:

```js
getLogos() {
  return fetch(...)
  ...
}

componentDidMount() {
  getLogos()
  .then(() => {
    transformarImagen();
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Didnt know fetch was a async function